# Localforage: switching between user-defined stores

Tags: localforage

I would like to be able to allow a user to switch between different stores in order to allow data to be isolated. For example, a user might be able to switch between several sets of data contained in a "March2020" store, or in "September2019".

I would also like to allow the previous store to be the default value when the program starts.

The problem I am facing is that you cannot change the Config once you have made a call to localforage, which I need to do to get the previous store:

```
const conf = localforage.config();

function getCurrentStore() {
    console.log(conf.name, conf.storeName);

        localforage.getItem('semYear').then(function(newStore) {  //This would get the current store name
            localforage.config({
                    storeName: newStore,
            });

            console.log("New store is: ", conf.name, conf.storeName);

            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
           });
};
```

Since I have already called "getItem", this does not change the store.

I could append the month and year to each database in the store (e.g. "addresses-March2020" or "nameData-March2020"), but  that seems horribly clunky.

I also tried

```
let currentMonth = getUserInput();

 currentMonth = localforage.createInstance({
  name: "nameHere"
});
```

But this just thinks I am trying to redefine the variable "currentMonth".

So what is the best way to allow a user to switch between different sets of data? I am sure I am missing something basic, but I cannot work it out, and it is important that I am able to prevent databases with the same name from contaminating each other.